# In-Reply-to and Reference had been added to email header but still send as new mail but not reply

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer, email-headers

I am trying to "reply" email via PHPmailer, but not "sending a new email", but I fail even the In-Reply-to and Reference had been added to email header, that means it shows it is still a new email,  the original email never been reply. Thanks for help.

My code:

```
  if($this->MessageID != '') {
  $result .= $this->HeaderLine('Message-ID',$this->MessageID);
} else {
  $result .= sprintf("Message-ID: <%s@%s>%s", $uniq_id, $this->ServerHostname(), $this->LE);
}

    if($this->References != ''){
            $result .= $this->HeaderLine('References',$this->References);
    }

    if($this->InReplyTo != ''){
            $result .= $this->HeaderLine('In-Reply-To',$this->InReplyTo);
    }

$result .= $this->HeaderLine('X-Priority', $this->Priority);
$result .= $this->HeaderLine('X-Mailer', 'PHPMailer '.$this->Version.' (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)');
```

The email header that send via phpmailer (which I fail,that means still a new email but not reply)

```
Date: Sat, 3 Dec 2016 17:01:21 +0800
To: Eric <erichu@test.com>
From: support <support@test.com>
Subject: Re:testemail12031604
Message-ID: <tencent_0634F549045841EE1B94753E@test.com>
References: <tencent_205C6E0F42D57AD16CFF6B9C@test.com>
In-Reply-To: <tencent_205C6E0F42D57AD16CFF6B9C@test.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.1 (phpmailer.sourceforge.net)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="b1_39519ee60f388e1a9b9a9ec312ae2071"
```

and this is header of a success reply email, that reply in web

```
From: "=?utf-8?B?RWxhaW5l?=" <support@test.com>
To: "=?utf-8?B?RXJpYw==?=" <erichu@test.com>
Subject: Re:hubreplytestemail12031604
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_5842871D_0A6F1F10_2B4284B6"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8Bit
Date: Sat, 3 Dec 2016 16:49:33 +0800
X-Priority: 3
Message-ID: <tencent_477F7F80668628EB4A87C531@test.com>
X-QQ-MIME: TCMime 1.0 by Tencent
X-Mailer: QQMail 2.x
X-QQ-Mailer: QQMail 2.x
References: <tencent_205C6E0F42D57AD16CFF6B9C@test.com>
In-Reply-To: <tencent_205C6E0F42D57AD16CFF6B9C@test.com>
X-QQ-ReplyHash: 2325734638
```

Comment: The subject lines should also be similar. See https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/965/how-does-gmail-decide-to-thread-email-messages

Comment: On "**it shows it is still a new email**": Who is the first "it"?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're using a very old version of PHPMailer; It's not been maintained on sourceforge for years, 5.1.0 was released in 2010! [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Why are you even looking at the internals of PHPMailer? You should just be calling `addCustomHeader()` to add the headers you want:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('References', '<tencent_205C6E0F42D57AD16CFF6B9C@test.com>');
$mail->addCustomHeader('In-Reply-To', '<tencent_205C6E0F42D57AD16CFF6B9C@test.com>');
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question by any means. I've also encountered the exact same problem using Python.